# I create table but it gives erros

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
  ClientID INT(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(15),
  LastName  VARCHAR(15),
  StreetAddress VARCHAR(25),
  Suburb VARCHAR(15),
  "State" VARCHAR(3),
  Postcode INT (4),
  PhoneNumber INT(10)
);
```

This is the error i got

> Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

Comment: The error message is quite clear.  
You can provide a width for int in mysql, you can't in SQL Server.

Comment: so can u tel the wrong

Comment: just get rid of the `(10)` and `(4)` behind the `INT` keywords and you should be fine

Comment: Change `INT(4)` to just `INT`

Comment: i got it (y) only int

Comment: INT won't work with a 10 digit phone number. Use NUMERIC(10) or a VARCHAR instead.

Comment: HOW TO PUT AUTO_INCREMENT IT AGIN GIVES ERROR

Comment: Try to read first please: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP should read the most basic documentation about SQL Server first.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write INT(4)

try this !

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
  ClientID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(15),
  LastName  VARCHAR(15),
  StreetAddress VARCHAR(25), 
  Suburb VARCHAR(15),
  State VARCHAR(3),
  Postcode INT, --should be varchar(10)
  PhoneNumber INT -- should be varchar(12)
);
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61f66)

[SEE HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187745.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

INT Data Type does not have a width. 
You have to write :
`ClientID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` instead of `ClientID INT(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Choice of data types aside (storing postcode in an int will work in the US but not internationally, also international phone numbers may be a problem), what you seem to want is a straight mapping from MySQL syntax including an auto incrementing key (in TSQL called IDENTITY)

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
  ClientID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(15),
  LastName  VARCHAR(15),
  StreetAddress VARCHAR(25),
  Suburb VARCHAR(15),
  "State" VARCHAR(3),
  Postcode INT,
  PhoneNumber NUMERIC(10)
);
```